# How to override a method in a class with another method from a class that is extending it

Tags: php, laravel

I'll try to describe my problem.

Let's say I have this class that, among other things, has this method:

```
class Article

...

  protected function getTitle(): string
  {
      return 'This is a title';
  }
```

and then I have this another class, extending the previous one

```
class CustomArticle extends Article

  protected function getTitle(): string
  {
      return 'This is a custom title';
  }
```

I have an array that contains the path to the first class, obtained using

```
$classPaths = [Article::class]
```

An that information is then stored on a database. The other custom class is in a different folder (the resources folder).

I istantiate the class in this way

```
$article = new [path retrived from the database];
```

What I want to happen, is that if i change the path on the database, I can istantiate the custom class, overriding the method while also inheriting all the other things from the Article class. I tried to copy the path of the ArticleCustom class on my db, but when i run the program i get this error saying

```
Error : Class [the path to the custom class] not found
```

I've tried all the paths: absolute, from content root, etc, both with "/" and "\"

Is it maybe because the custom class inherits the namespace of the original one, but it's actually not in that folder? I tried using the path of the Article class, and just adding "Custom" at the end of it, but it doesn't work

I've looked on laracast and other stackoverflow posts, but I can't find an answer to this.

What would be the proper way to do this? Keeping if possible the structure I described.

Comment: that isn't a path its a fully qualified class name, what ever the fully qualified class name is for the class you want is what you would be 'new'ing up ... but if you are not storing the FQCN for the class you want then I don't know what you are doing

Comment: what i have on the db now is the FQCN of the article class, which gets correctly 'newed' when i use new followed by the FQCN. What i would like to achive is that by changin the FQCN on the database, the ArticlesCustom class gets "newed" thus overriding the method.

Comment: I tried creating another class on the same folder as Article that extends Article, and if i new on that class everything works. But if i do the same process but creating the custom class in another folder, it doesn't work, giving me the same error as before

Comment: Quick update: i managed to make it work by adding the resources folder in the psr-4 autoload, but it's a very bad solution.. Any idea on how to use classes that are outside the App namespace?

Comment: @jack can you give me the exact paths of both custom article and article please, namespaces

Comment: Path of the article class: 
'app/ArticleGenerator/Article.php'


PAth of the custom class: 
'resources/custom-articles/CustomArticle.php'


From what understood so far, laravel wasn't able to find my custom article cass because it's not part of the App namespace. What i did was insert the resources/custom-articles path inside the psr-4 autoload, and then run the command composer dump-autoload. That way Laravel loaded my external classes, and i was able to use them as i described in the post (so by retriving the FQCN from db)

Comment: @Ballard reply is on top of this comment